# How can I see the possible values on a column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am working with Colab, I have a very large column and I want to see the possible values that are in this column.

Comment: Like `df[col].value_counts()`?

Answer (score 0):

- for numeric columns use: describe()
- for categorical columns use : value_counts()